# TinyMCE background highlighter plugin

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have added below toolbar and plugin options to my TinyMCE:

```
toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | table | image | link | fontselect | fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor"

plugins:
  - image
  - link
  - textcolor
```

Now I want to add plugin attached in image:

[image: this pliugin in windows word works like - it adds background highlighter. I also don't know the name of the plugin. So I am unable to google it]

Comment: add colorpicker plugin

Comment: It adds custom color option to forecolor or backcolor. But I want something which allows me to add backround color or remove background color

Comment: The color pickers allow you to both set and remove colors so the product does what you want it to do already.  There is an `x` in the color picker list.  Selecting that removes the color.

Answer (score 0):

You should add backcolor to your toolbar items list:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    [...]
    toolbar: "backcolor"
});
```